# np.where resulted in length of values does not match

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have used  column to filter and create new column

```
df['brought_profit_to_company'] = np.where([(df['product_id'] == '7.99_7free') & (df['trial'] == True)], 0, 5)
df.head()
```

But It has resulted in error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/common.py in require_length_match(data, index)
    530     if len(data) != len(index):
    531         raise ValueError(
--> 532             "Length of values "
    533             f"({len(data)}) "
    534             "does not match length of index "

ValueError: Length of values (1) does not match length of index (62874)
```

Here is my dataframe:

```
    user_id product_id  trial   refunded    purchase_date_x country_code    media_source    days_used_app
0   2589061 7.99_7free  True    False   2020-09-27  JO  Facebook Ads    7 days
1   2604470 9.99    False   False   2020-09-29  UK  Facebook Ads    7 days
2   2274467 9.99    False   False   2020-08-18  Organic/Unknown Organic/Unknown 21 days
3   2274467 9.99    False   False   2020-09-01  Organic/Unknown Organic/Unknown 21 days
4   2274467 9.99    False   False   2020-08-25  Organic/Unknown Organic/Unknown 21 days
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the [] from the where function, it should be like this instead:

```
df['brought_profit_to_company'] = np.where((df['product_id'] == '7.99_7free') & (df['trial'] == True), 0, 5)
```